# Cloud-based automation testing tool that supports Selenium and Java

Tags: automation

So my project has been using saucelab as automation testing suite (with scheduled daily jobs via Jenkins) for quite some time, but lately we've faced several connectivity issues from saucelab (they even emailed out to our team apologizing for recent problems and promised to improve their service). I'm looking at alternative tools which satisfy some of these criterias

- Selenium friendly, we write our automation test code in Java
- Jenkins integration is a plus, but not a must
- Capture live videos, snapshots
- Can run parallel tests
- Cloud-based
- Cross browser (Chrome primarily)
- Mobile testing is nice to have but totally optional

So far I've found BrowserStack, and GhostLab does offer 7-days which is nice.

If anyone has any recommendations, and/or has used any of similar tools I'd hope to hear your feedback and advices.

Cheers

Comment: Please replace "great" with a measurable metric, thanks!